# Local storage is not working to store checkboxes in todo app REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to store checkboxes in local storage so data still persists even if I navigate to a different page. The problem I am having is I keep getting this error,

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

What I'm trying to do is every time a user adds a checkbox, I want it to be added to local storage using `useEffect`. However, I don't know how to retrieve the data from local storage after every update. I just get the same error message displayed above. Here's the code below.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {Delete, Refresh, Add} from "../components/Actions";
import {Header} from "../components/Header";
import {PriorityLists} from "../components/PriorityLists";
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';

function Task() {
    
    
    const [toDo, setToDo] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks') || '[]'));
    const [idsToRefresh, setIdsToRefresh] = useState([]);
    const [filter_items, setFilterItems] = useState(false);
    const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
       
     
        localStorage.setItem('tasks',  JSON.stringify(toDo));
       
       

        
     
    }, [toDo]);

    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(toDo[0] !== undefined) {
            setToDo(toDo.filter(item=> {
                return !ids.includes(item._Id);
            }))
        }


    }, [filter_items]);

    function addIds(checked, id_to_be_deleted) {
        if(!checked) {
            setIds((item)=> [...item, id_to_be_deleted]);
        }
        else {
            setIds(ids.filter(item=> {
                return item !== id_to_be_deleted;
            }))
        }
    }



    function addToDos() {
        const id = uuidv4();
        setToDo(toDo.concat({_Id: id, value:<PriorityLists id = {id} checked = {false} addIds = {addIds} />}));
        setIdsToRefresh(idsToRefresh.concat(id));
      
      
    }

  
    

    function refresh() {
        setToDo(toDo.filter(item=> {
            return !idsToRefresh.includes(item._Id);
        }))
    }



    return (
    <div className = "main-content">
        <div className = "container-fluid">
            <div className = "row underline">
                <div className= "col">
                    <div className = "row">
                    <div className = "col-3 pt-2">
                        <Refresh _refresh = {refresh} />
                    </div>

                    <div className = "col-6 text-center">
                        <Header header ={"Tasks"}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className = "col-3 pt-2">
                        <button  className = "float-right">
                            <Delete setFilterItems = {setFilterItems} filter = {filter_items} />
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className = "row">
                <div className = "col">
          
                   {
                   
                       
                   toDo.map(item=> {
                       return (<div key = {item._Id}> 
                       <ul>
                           <li>{item.value} </li>
                         
                       </ul>
                       </div>)
                   })}
                    
                   
 
                    
                </div>
            </div>


            <div className = "row">
                
                <div className = "col pr-4">
        
                    <Add addToDos = {addToDos} />
                
                </div>
            </div>



        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    )
}

export default Task;
```

Comment: I think localStorage.getItem() returns you a `String` and that might be the issue? Not sure

Comment: @SinanYaman - You can see that the OP's code parses that string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So what is the solution here?

Comment: @Ron - I don't know, there's far too much cruft above. Please update your question with a [mre] -- note the "minimal." :-) But fundamentally, the error message is quite clear: You're trying to use an object that isn't a React element as a child, which React doesn't allow.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right. I know I'm not supposed to have an object as a child. That is why I'm figuring what is it that's causing that problem. The initial value I put is this in hook-> useState(Json.parse(localstorage.getItem('tasks') || '[]'.  This should be able to return an empty array.  I have use effect to set the array of toDos in local storage everytime user clicks but I don't know why it's returning an object. It  should be an array of objects.

Comment: @Ron - You're seem to be talking about state data. That's not what the error is about. The error is about using an object as a child element, e.g.: `<div>{someObject}</div>`.